# Nantes airport shuttle details

Tags: public-transport, france, nte

Could anyone supply me with details of the shuttle bus operating at Nantes airport (France) - times, costs, etc.

Answer (score 8):

The shuttle between the Nantes airport (Aéroport de Nantes Atlantique, NTE) and the city of Nantes has a price of 9 euros/trip (November 2017). They call it the 'navette aéroport'. The service frequency is 20 minutes, and it takes about 35 minutes to get the airport from the city centre. More (and updated) info can be found here: https://www.nantes.aeroport.fr/fr/acces-et-transports/navette-aeroport | https://naolib.fr/fr/transports-en-commun/tram-bus-navibus

The 'navette' ticket is NOT included in the tourist pass (https://www.levoyageanantes.fr/a-faire/pass-nantes/) or any other ticket offers (https://www.tan.fr/fr/menu/titres-tarifs/tan/tous-les-tarifs/).

To go to the airport from the city centre, you can also take tramway 3 up to the end of line (Neustrie) and then take bus 48 from there to the airport. It has the same cost as a normal trip.

To sum up:

- Navette - Expensive but faster.
- Tram 3 + bus 48 - Cheaper but slower.